# Entity Framework Core 3.1 how can I order by field from another table

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables, Examples:

For illustrative purpose only. I didn't list all the codes here. It is quite lengthly.

```
Employee
    EmployeeID
    OpenID
    JoinDate

OAuth
    OpenID
    Name
```

I wish my query wish to order by either **Name** or **JoinDate** depends on which column the user wish to sort. This is how I did normally:

```
var qry = from q in db.Employee select q;

switch (sortField)
{
    case "JoinDate": qry = from q in qry orderby q.JoinDate select q; break;
    case "Name": qry = from q in qry orderby q.OAuth.Name select q; break;
}
```

The relationship between the Employee and OAuth are one to one. It is able query when we sort by **JoinDate**. But failed to join the two tables and sort them correctly if the option is **Name**.

Error message is:

```
OrderBy(t => t.OAuth.Name)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

If I remember correctly, we should be able to do this in linq2sql.

Comment: If the `OAuth` navigation property is mapped properly, order by `t.OAuth.Name` should work. Are you sure it is not decorated with `[NotMapped]` attribute or ignored via fluent API?

Comment: Yes, someone put a notmapped attribute. Thanks